# Spring Boot 2.4.3 - Actuator /startup endpoint not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot app that I upgraded from v2.2.x to now be v2.4.3.

I saw in their documentation that there is a new actuator endpoint of `/startup`, however it does not exist when I start my app.
[image]

There is no special requirement according to their documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#startup)

I am using `spring-boot-admin-starter-client` v2.4.3 which provides `spring-boot-actuator` v2.4.3, and i even have `management.endpoint.startup.enabled=true` in my application.properties file.

Has anyone else used this version of spring boot and gotten this actuator enpoint to work?

Comment: Please, don't post pictures of the text, as the raw text is more maintainable, simpler and lighter to be included in the posts.

Comment: Have you tried `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`. Since /health and /info are enabled by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tweak startup configuration:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
        app.setApplicationStartup(new BufferingApplicationStartup(1000));
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

In application.properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=startup
```

If you want to visualize startup events check out this tool I made some months ago https://spring-boot-startup-analyzer.netlify.app/ (look at the configuration instructions as you need to enable CORS on this endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using BootstrapApplicationListener which build the application context again but ignores the previous applicationStartup, so it sets the default, this is a bug in spring-cloud-context:3.0.0

Comment: spring-cloud-context is irrelevant for this question.